# How to increment conditionally?

Tags: java

so im a complete beginner and I was wondering if it was possible to increment a counter conditionally. I am trying to count the letter “I” in a sentence and everytime i pass an “I”, i want counter to increment by 1 but if there is more than 1 of these together “III” it still only increments by 1 until there a character after it like “IIIaI” which would count as 2 instances.
    Is this possible?
    Sorry guys, here is my code:

```
public static int countTheIs(string sentence){
        int iCounter = 0;
        String iCount = "iI"; //both cases included
        for (int j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++){
            char ch =sentence.charAt(j);
            if (iCount.indexOf(ch) != -1){
           iCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What doesn't work in the code? We'd love to help, but we need some code in order to do so.

Comment: No shame of being complete beginner, but you should have read how to post a good question on SO as you did not provide the code of your attempts!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: So, you need to check if the previous char is `l` before incrementing. Just do that.

Comment: Do you know how to read a `String`  `char` by `char` ? Then you have the first step. Do you know how to write a condition like `character == 'l'` ? You have the second step, and how to increment an numeric like `counter++;`, you are almost done here, just need to only increment once if you find the character in sequence. That part is a bit more tricky and can be done in different way, I would go with an inner loop to increment until the next char isn't a `l`. I let you write this and then I will help you more ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually quite far already, all you need to do is to check the previous character. This can be done the following way:

```
String sentence = "Test i two II three iIi";        
int iCounter = 0;
String iCount = "iI"; 
for (int j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++){
    char current = sentence.charAt(j);
    char previous; //1
    if (j==0) { 
        previous = 'Z';  //2
    } else {
        previous = sentence.charAt(j-1); //3
    }
    if (iCount.indexOf(current) != -1 && iCount.indexOf(previous) == -1 ){ //4
        iCounter++;
   }
}
```

Let me explain to you what I have done, according to my // tags

//1  We make a new `char` variable holding the previous character.
//2  Because the first index of the String has no previous characters, we will set it to a random, non-matching character to prevent errors at the start. I picked `Z` in this example.
//3  If there is a previous character, we get this by subtracting 1 from `j`
//4  We check in the if statement if the currenct character *is* in `iCount`, and the previous character *is not* in `iCount`. If this is the case, the counter will increase.

When the above code is ran, the result will output `3`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to assume that you have a string input, you are counting by using a loop and then using `charAt(x)`(x is the number you use to increment the loop) and then comparing.

Simply check if `charAt(x-1)` is also I. If it is, then don't increment `i`. Also, you want to make sure `x>0` otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: thank you! I understand that I could have iCounter++ if I am trying to increment but if there is an instance where I am not trying to increment the counter even though an I is present (in the case of multiple i characters), how do I do that?

Comment: Ok, I made a few more edits. its just that i is normally used to loop. So, the way you get around that is at the part where I said charAt(x-1) is also I. If x > 0 and charAt(x-1) is an I, then you don't need to increment. only when the charAt(x-1) is not I and charAt(x) is an I should you increment.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the below code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CountI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "IIiaIii";
        String regex = "([A-Za-z])\\1+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        String output = matcher.replaceAll("$1");
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++){
            if(output.charAt(i) == 73 || output.charAt(i) == 105){
                result++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

2

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score -2):

You want Regular Expressions and the Java `Pattern` class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

In my sample below I used "w" instead of "l" because it's easier to distinguish.  Using regular expressions, define a pattern that will capture one or more consecutive occurrences of the letter: `w+`, then use a matcher, count the number of times it matches.

```
String input = "wwowwee w w w";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("w+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
int count = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
  count++;
}
System.out.println("Count: " + count);
```

Or, simply split the string and count the number of splits:

```
String input = "wwowwee w w w";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("w+");
String[] tokens = p.split(input);
System.out.println("token count: " + tokens.length);
```

Both give the correct results.

Edit: This doesn't answer the question about incrementing a counter conditionally, but it solves the problem that question was posed to address.

Comment: While I like the answer, I am downvoting it because it does not answer the OP's  question about conditional counter increment. It might solve the problem, but perhaps the OP intended to learn more about counters.